# Deleting records referentially linked between tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a two tables A and B - A has a referentially linked one-to-many relationship with B.

A and B are linked by 'ID'

I want to delete all records from A and B where the date last updated (from Table B) is more than x weeks ago.

I have an SQL statement that will list the cases as I would expect, but I can't get the delete function to work.

The SQL returns ~8500 records grouped by A.ID where B.DateUpdated is less than Today - 84

```sql
SELECT Max(B.DateUpdated) AS [Date Last Updated], A.ID 
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID 
GROUP BY A.ID 
HAVING (((Max(B.DateUpdated))<=Date()-84));
```

This outputs what I would expect, but I am really struggling on how to delete records from two tables - if I play around with the DELETE syntax, it suggests I need to specify a table I wish to delete from and I'm not sure what best to google or search for to clarify.

I appreciate this will probably fall into "RTFM" but everything I have googled so far hasn't gone into ELI5 enough detail for me to 'get' it

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you familiar with cascade delete feature of enforced referential integrity? However, why bother deleting records? Deleting really should be a rare event. Apply filter criteria to exclude records from selection for output to reports.

Comment: @June7, MS Access doesn't support `ON DELETE CASCADE` functionality. Also it is better to remove the unnecessary records from the table to limit the size of the table.

Comment: @oliver, I think you need to delete them manually one by one.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai That is correct, it is to limit the size of the table - it isn't something I created, just have to maintain from time to time and given the speed of the network and the inefficient way the tool was made some of the queries take a long time.

I feared as much, I thought I'd have to delete them one by one.

Another idea I'd had was to use the ID column to delete each item in table B before doing the same in table A

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, what do you mean Access doesn't support cascade delete? Certainly does. I just used it. Delete main record and dependent records also delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming cascade delete activated with enforced referential integrity in relationships builder, run delete on primary table and dependent records in related table will also delete. Use your query that returns the ID of records that must be deleted as criteria for the delete.

```
DELETE FROM A WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM query1);
```

Comment: I genuinely had no idea I could reference the output of a query like this, that was really helpful - and worked like a charm!